# How to remove an specific event listener from window using native javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Note: I know there are a couple of questions on how to remove a specific event listener, but my use case is something specific.

I want to remove a specific event listener from 'window' element.

Something like :-

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

window.removeAllEventListener("message");

The following is a custom drupal plugin :-

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'aemassetpicker', {
// Register the icons. They must match command names.
icons: 'aemassetpicker',

// The plugin initialization logic goes inside this method.
init: function( editor ) {

    CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load( 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');

    var assetPickerURL = "https://localhost/aem/assetpicker";

    var style = "popup";

    var popup;

    function _popup(url) {
        popup = window.open(url, "dam", "left=25%,top=25%,height=800,width=1600,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=yes");
        //popup = window.open(url, "dam");
        //console.log("popup");
        //console.log(popup);
    }

    // Define the editor command that inserts a dailog.
    editor.addCommand( 'insertAEMAssets', {
        exec: function( editor ) {

            var img_asset;
            var title_asset;
            var url_asset;
            var type_asset;
            var size_asset;

            //$(window).off('message').on('message', receiveMessage);
            window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

            var url = assetPickerURL;

            _popup(url);

            function receiveMessage (event) {
                // Don’t accept messages from other sources!
                if (assetPickerURL.indexOf(event.origin) != 0) {
                    return;
                }

                var fromDam = JSON.parse(event.data);

                console.log("fromDam");
                console.log(fromDam);

                if (fromDam.config) {
                    var configFromDam = fromDam.config;

                    if (configFromDam.action === 'close' || configFromDam.action === 'done') {
                        if (popup) {
                            popup.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (fromDam.data) {
                    var dam_detail = fromDam.data;

                    for (var i in dam_detail) {
                        img_asset = dam_detail[i].img;
                        title_asset = dam_detail[i].title;
                        url_asset = dam_detail[i].url;
                        type_asset = dam_detail[i].type;
                        size_asset = dam_detail[i].size;
                        //console.log(img_asset);
                        //console.log(title_asset);
                        //console.log(url_asset);
                        //console.log(type_asset);
                        //console.log(size_asset);
                        editor.insertHtml( '<img src="' + url_asset + '/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.319.319.png" alt="' + title_asset + '"></img>' );
                    }
                }

                window.removeEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
            }
        }
    });

    // Create the toolbar button that executes the above command.
    editor.ui.addButton( 'AEMAssetPicker', {
        label: 'Insert AEM Assets',
        command: 'insertAEMAssets',
        toolbar: 'basicstyles,0',
        allowedContent: true
    });

}
});
```

What i have tried :-

1. Moving the callback receiveMessage to the top, but it needs to be inside for the editor.insertHtml to be called.
2. If i use window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false); outside the function it doesn't work because the function address changes each time.
3. window.removeEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
   before window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false); but again there is no callback function with the same address so still another event listener gets created.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Stupid solution: I just used a simple flag to check if the event listener was already created

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the original function used with `addEventListener`, you cannot remove it with the DOM API. You need that function reference to call `removeEventListener`.

So if you want to do this, you need to store the `receiveMessage` function that you've added somewhere, and then use it when removing it. E.g., declare a variable within the plugin:

```
var lastReceiveMessage = null;
```

then:

```
if (lastReceiveMessage) {
    window.removeEventListener("message", lastReceiveMessage, false);
}
lastReceiveMessage = receiveMessage;
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
```

and later when you remove it because you got the message you wanted:

```
window.removeEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
if (lastReceiveMessage == receiveMessage) {
    lastReceiveMessage = null;
}
```